# incorrect behavior 'onselectstart' in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

There is draggable element which must move with a 'move' cursor. The cursor will become like at selecting when I move the element. I tried to use `.onselectstart = function(e) { return false }` on 'mousedown' and `.onselectstart = null` on 'mouseup'. It works good. But it stops working after any select on the page. I observe it in Google Chrome and Maxthon only.

So, take a look http://jsfiddle.net/JqMgE/1/

Sometimes needs select a few times to call this bug.

Comment: I see the problem now. First select some of the text top, left, then try to drag the `Draggable` red box/text. You get the text selection cursor `ondragstart`.

Comment: So. I solve it by using event.preventDefault() on 'mousedown' and 'mousemove'. http://jsfiddle.net/JqMgE/2/

Comment: Of course! Should have thought of that. You should post that as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem by using `event.preventDefault()` `onmousedown` and `onmousemove`.

http://jsfiddle.net/JqMgE/2

There is no need to use `.onselectstart`.

Comment: You can accept this as the answer, too, by clicking the outlined checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: ”You can accept your own answer in 2 days” and nothing else happens